# Skill matching algorithm

Tags: database, algorithm, search, matching

I need to implement a skill matching feature similar to http://venturocket.com - a candidate enters a list of skills and rates his proficiency for each. You can then search by again entering some skills and the level of expertise you are looking for. The result is a list of candidates ordered by how well their skills match your search.

Example:

Candidate 1 enters skill Java (proficiency 90) and candidate 2 enters Java (50). When I search for Java (60) candidate 2 is a closer match.

This shold also work with multiple skills.

What I'm looking for are pointers to technologies or algorithms that would help me achieve this. My current approach would be to do a range query in a database (e.g. look for Java skills between 45 and 75) and then sort on the client, but that wouldn't be very fast.

Comment: Letting people enter their own proficiency within a large scale will be really hard to make something of. Just saying. I don't mean programmatically of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the value that you are checking against in as a parameter for the query and then use the Euclidean Distance (the square of the difference) to sort:

```
SELECT TOP 20 * -- added a TOP 20 as example, choose/limit as appropriate for your situation
FROM Candidate
ORDER BY SQUARE(Candidate.JavaProficiency - @JavaProficiency) + SQUARE(Candidate.SqlProficiency - @SqlProficiency)
```

For multiple traits you sum up each of the square differences.

See [Wikipedia: Euclidean Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) for a bit more detail (specifically the "Squared Euclidean Distance" section).  Note that this answer is actually DanRedux's (see comments/edits).

Comment: A more accurate method for determining a Candidates closeness is simply Cartesian distance, treating each level of proficiency as a dimension, which means to sum up the square's of each difference in skill. Suppose, as with your example, two Candidates had Java(50), SQL(70), and another with Java(60), SQL(40), and someone searches for Java(60), SQL(60), the respective distances would be 200, 400, so the first candidate would be selected. This is just Cartesian distance, treating each level of skill as it's own dimension, and finding the closest coordinate to the passed in.

Comment: @DanRedux - you are correct, much more appropriate.  You should make your comment an answer, then you can have the rep! :)

Comment: Naw, I don't much care for rep seeing as I can help people with just 1 rep.

Answer (score 2):

If I was asked to implement something like this, I would start by looking at clustering algorithms.

By grouping candidates together based on how they are similar on a number of properties (skills), it would be easy to figure out what cluster of candidates most likely match your search parameters.

k-means clustering is fairly easy to use and would probably be a good place to start.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

There are solid implementations of k-means in most programming languages, so getting started should be fairly easy.

There's a lot of good information about cluster based filtering in Programming Collective Intelligence — http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529321.do

Answer (score 0):

You could treat this as an [information retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval) problem and use [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

This involves forming for each candidate a vector of what scores they entered for each tag.  Unmentioned tags get a score of 0.  Queries are transformed similarly, letting the user request a score for each tag, or perhaps just treating mentioned tags as high scores, etc.  Using dot products and magnitudes, one can compute a similarity score between the query and each candidate; sort and choose the top highest.

Those are the broad strokes for implementing it yourself.  In any serious application I'd suggest you *not* do that, and instead dust off something like [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) to do it for you.

Comment: If you use the dot product of skill-as-vector vs query-as-vector, then in the case where, for example, 'java' is not part of the query, do you end up preferring candidates for whom 'java=0'?  That seems wrong - won't you need to project each vector onto just the dimensions involved?

Comment: Fair point; I'm deliberately simplifying.  There are whole books (for example http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/ ) about getting this right; my explanation is just to illustrate.  That is also why I suggest serious attempts use an existing search appliance instead.